# Want to create Rewriterule for username in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i m creating a website in that site you can access you profile with entering your Username in the url. like http://www.example.com/username

i have created the .htaccess file and add the rewriterule for the username. See below

```
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+]+)$ index.php?p=home&username=$1 [S=1]
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+]+)/$ index.php?p=home&username=$1 [S=1]
```

It works perfectly when enter the username in the url. but when i add the username including the . operator it will not works. See below

```
Works with this
http://www.example.com/username
```

But

```
Not works with this
http://www.example.com/user.name
```

Can any body help me what to change in my rewriterule to working with dot(.) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `([_A-Z0-9a-z-+]+)` to include matching against the dot: `([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)`

EDIT:

Add RewriteCond before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=home&username=$1 [L]
```

Or alternatively, to avoid rewriting other PHP files or files that exist, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=home&username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it dont work. i will return "index.php" as username. Still i m stuck with this i need help.
Thanks

Comment: You can combine the 2 rules (with a `/?` optional match) and add a condition before it. See my edit.